# Problemas al relacionar 2 campos en odoo 11

Tags: odoo

estoy desarrollando un modulo en odoo 11 pero he tenido un inconveniente al relacionar unos campos el codigo no me genera un error pero al visualizar en vez de salir el nombre del paciente aparece el nombre de la tabla junto con el id del registro [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
adjunto el codigo que he utilizado

```
class pacientes(models.Model):
    _name ='pacientes'
paciente_id = fields.One2many('calendar.event', 'pacientes_ids', 'Citas', required=False, ondelete='cascade')

class citas(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'calendar.event'

    pacientes_ids = fields.Many2one('pacientes', 'Pacientes:', ondelete='cascade')

<field name="arch" type="xml">
       <field name="partner_ids" position="after">
                    <field name="pacientes_ids" />
       </field>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema aparentemente es que no tienes definido dentro de "Pacientes" un atributo "name", por lo tanto Odoo te lo va a renderizar como la tabla y el id.

Aunque no pones todo el código de la clase paciente, es muy probable que quieras usar otros campos, entre ellos un identificador del paciente (nombre y apellidos, algún número de registro, etc). Te sugiero que uses ese identificador como el campo "name"